# Understanding the PATH variable and soft link

Tags: ls

Please help me understand what `my-ls -l ~/bin/my-ls` is trying to do? I have run the following commands on a Linux system:

```bsh
$ ln -s $(which ls) ~/bin/my-ls   # symlink
$ which my-ls
/home/user/bin/my-ls
$ my-ls -l ~/bin/my-ls
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 7 2010-10-27 18:56 my-ls -> /bin/ls
$ my-ls          # lookup through $PATH
bin  desktop  documents  downloads  examples.desktop  music
$ ~/bin/my-ls    # doesn't use $PATH to lookup
bin  desktop  documents  downloads  examples.desktop  music
```

Comment: It looks like `my-ls` is currently just pointing at the base system `/bin/ls`, so it is not doing anything other than execute `ls` when you type `my-ls`. As for why it is set u to do this, you do not provide enough information to make a guess.

Answer (score 0):

It's listing the properties of the symbolic link that was created by the first `ln -s $(which ls) ~/bin/my-ls` command.

It also proves that you can give parameters to a command that is called through a symbolic link, and the parameters won't change at all: effectively, the `my-ls -l ~/bin/my-ls` runs `/bin/ls -l ~/bin/my-ls`.